# Prove the statements are equal. Set Theory.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm not sure I'm on the right track here.  I have to prove these 3 statements are equal, so I know I have to prove, if a then b, if b then c, if c then a.

a. A ⊆ B
b. A ∩ B ̅  = ∅ 
c. A ̅  ∪ B = U

a ⇒ b  
Show if A ⊆ B, then A ∩ B ̅  = ∅ 
A ⊆ B ⇒A ∩ B= A  -------- by Proposition 3.14 (b) in the study guide. 
 ⇒ A ∩ U= A --------------- U=B, by identity laws
 ⇒ A ∩ B ̅= ∅   ----------------    B ̅=U ̅  = ∅, by complement laws

b ⇒ c  
Show if  A ∩ B ̅  = ∅, then A ̅  ∪ B = U
         A ∩ B ̅= ∅    ⇒ A ̅  ∪ B ̿= ∅ ̅   --------------   complement both sides of equation and 
de Morgan’s laws
                ⇒ A ̅  ∪ B= U  -------------------------------- double complement

c ⇒ a 
 Show if A ̅  ∪ B = U, then A ⊆ B
        A ̅  ∪ B = U    ⇒ (A ̅  ∪ B = U) ̅      ----------------    complement both sides of equation
                ⇒ A ∩ B ̅  = ∅  --------------------------------    de Morgan’s laws, double complement

And I'm sorta stuck here...  but if my previous work isn't correct, I need to make sure I'm going in the right direction before I can finish the proof.

Comment: $U$ is probably the universe, isn't it? So $B^- = U \setminus B$, which is not necessarily $\emptyset$.

Comment: For $a \implies b$: $\varnothing = A \setminus A = A\cap U \setminus A\cap B \stackrel{dist}{=} A\cap (U \setminus B) = A\cap \overline{B}$, where **dist** is short for the distributive law

Comment: Thanks!... took me awhile to understand, but i got that.  Am I correct in assuming b then c is a simple as stated?  It really just seems like the complement. My c then a also seems like it's just the reverse of the whole thing... which I don't think is good proofing.

Comment: As far as I can see, only the last line in your "$a \implies b$" proof was an issue. For the "$c\implies a$" proof, you have actually proven $c\implies b$. You could prove $b \implies a$ to complete the proof, e.g. $A = A \setminus \varnothing = (A\cap U) \setminus (A\cap \overline{B}) \stackrel{dist}{=} A\cap (U \setminus \overline{B}) \ldots$

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  Feel much more confident now!